# Directory path with space

Tags: qt

Maybe you think this question is solved more and more before, but I have another problem.
For example the directory path is “C:\Program Files (x86)\sth”.
I don`t set it directly! I get it from registry. So, the directory path maybe different in another systems.
How can I change the directory path to a valid one dynamically?

Thanks a lot.

Ya Ali.

Comment: Change to a valid path? The path with a space **is** valid. Need actual code and actual problem.

Comment: For example “C:\Program Files (x86)\sth” must change to “C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\sth”

Comment: That second path - where do you consider it "valid"? Is that supposed to be a shell input? You need to tell us the context in which the "path" is to be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Searching a lot and finding nothing major!

But I wrote my own codes.

```
    QList<QString> lst = installedPath.split("\\");
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size(); i++)
    {
        if(lst.at(i).indexOf(" ") != -1)
        {
            validLocation += "\"";
            validLocation += lst.at(i);
            validLocation += "\"";
            validLocation += "\\\\";
        }
        else
        {
            validLocation += lst.at(i);
            if(i != lst.size()-1)
                validLocation += "\\\\";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to put all folder names containing spaces in quotes. Instead put all the path in quotes if it contains a space character.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this path from a registry, than it's backslashes should be already escaped (same as if you use cin to get a string and there's a backslash), so the path should be valid. If it's somehow not working for you, you can try and use `QDir::fromNativeSeparators()` [QtDoc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#fromNativeSeparators). It will change backslash to slash, which Qt can deal with on Windows too.

Comment: pay attention to the space! fromNativeSeparators() does not work for solving space problem.

Comment: please answer if you are sure about you are saying! I must execute an exe file in that directory. I can`t by your answer because of the space!

Comment: Read again the example. That`s not for my problem. I said that did not wrok for me. I tested and the problem is only for the space of the path

Answer (score -1):

Try double slash after drive symbol:  “C://Program Files (x86)/sth”

Comment: Wrong kind of slash there ... change those to back slashes.

Comment: It works for me on Windows 10 :) I use it to find specific executable inside Program Files folder and its subfolders.